# Using Location in ViewModelFactory

Tags: android

I am new in Android and I am working on a project using GoogleMap. It is an application with three fragments : one with the map, one with a list of restaurant (search with api search of googleapi) and one with workmates list.
I wanted to create a ModelView to save the list of restaurant that i will be using in the two first fragment.

In my MainActivity I want to get the Location of the user (using FusedLocationProviderClient) and reinject the Location in my ViewModel.

My MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    key = getString(R.string.api_google_place_key);

    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                my_location = location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
                mModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,new RestaurantViewModelFactory(key,my_location)).get(RestaurantViewModel.class);
            }
        }
    });
    configureToolBar();
    configureDrawerLayout();
    configureNavigationView();
    initFragment();
    configureBottomOnClick();
    updateProfileData();
}
```

I have an issue because `this` in the line:

```
mModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,new RestaurantViewModelFactory(key,my_location)).get(RestaurantViewModel.class);
```

is not recognized.

How can i call My MainActivity?

I would like to create my mModel only when the Location provided by FusedLocationProviderClient is success. That is why I have placed the mModel inside the OnSuccess.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `MainActivity.this` instead of `this` (refers to `OnSuccessListener`):

```
mModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MainActivity.this, new RestaurantViewModelFactory(key,my_location)).get(RestaurantViewModel.class);`
```